# Flutter activity is not navigating after the message is received from native iOS side via MethodChannel

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, communication, flutter-method-channel

I am developing flutter app which needs to present native UI and to achieve this I am using `MethodChannel` to make a connection between `flutter` and iOS `Native` and I am able to pass data from flutter view to native and navigating native UI and once Native UI is dismissed then am sending message back to flutter.
I am struggling with navigating flutter screen after message is received from native side.

Let me explain more in detail :
I have created a channel object and then calling native function from flutter as:

```
        Future<Null> _openNewPage() async {
           final response = await channel.invokeMethod("openPage", ["Hi From Flutter"]);
        }
```

iOS Code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
        let flutterController : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel: FlutterMethodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "CHANNEL", binaryMessenger: flutterController.binaryMessenger)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler { [unowned self] (methodCall, result) in
            guard let arg = (methodCall.arguments as! [String]).first else { return }
            
            switch methodCall.method {
            case "openPage":
                self.openSecondPage(result: result)

            default:
                debugPrint(methodCall.method)
                result(methodCall.method)
              }
       }
```

`self.openSecondPage` method has code of navigating Native iOS UI and it is working correctly.

Once that UI is dismiss the result message is passed through parameter to flutter. This method handles the result here  `Future<dynamic> _handleMethod(MethodCall call) async {}`.

in that method I am pushing flutter activity as:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PreviewActivity(videoFile: path)));
```

But this didn't work can anyone please guide me.

UPDATED:

Native code that pass data to flutter view:

```
    let flutterVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "CHANNEL", binaryMessenger: flutterVC as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
    channel.invokeMethod("sendFromNative", arguments: path)
```

and in flutter side I have implemented code as :

```
DashBoardParentScreen({Key key, this.guestUserType}) : super(key: key){
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(_handleMethod);
  }

Future<dynamic> _handleMethod(MethodCall call) async {
    switch (call.method) {
      case 'sendFromNative':
        String text = call.arguments as String;
        print("PathFromNative::  $text");
        pushPreviewScreen(text);
    }
  }


pushPreviewScreen(String path){
     print("calledFunction::  $path");
     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PreviewActivity(videoFile: path)));
  }
```

Once native method sends a message to flutter side then I need to show other preview screen.

Comment: your native ios code is unable to invoke your dart method, am i right? or writing to the result object once the native UI is dismissed?

Comment: post your native `.invokeMethod()` code

Comment: I have updated question and `pushPreviewScreen` this method has navigation code that part is not working

Comment: `print("PathFromNative::  $text");` does this log correctly? if not did you check channel names given on both side? please use something other than 'CHANNEL'